# Error:(33, 0) Could not find property 'compile' on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@3da55115

Tags: android, android-studio

there is a problem to sync of my project. when i was add some dependencies in build.gradle file, it through some errors, please help me

there is my code :

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'http://clojars.org/repo'
    } }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

        compile 'com.pusher:pusher-java-client:1.0.0'
        // for our HTTP requests later
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4', // for parsing JSON
                compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
         compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.1.1' // for image rendering
    }
```

Comment: Did you solved your problem yet ??

Answer (score 1):

compile as a property. You should use proper **FORMAT** .

**Don't**

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4', // Remove ,
```

**Do**

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
```